# PHP send mail from addresses in database

Tags: php

I've read & tried a few posts but can't get this problem solved.  I'm trying to send mail to addresses in a database, but get the following error:  **Warning: mail() expects parameter 3 to be string, array given ...**

```
include 'datalogin.php';
$sql10 = "SELECT * FROM ex_usrs_admin_dept WHERE linked_dept = '$newdept1'";
$res10 = mysql_query($sql10);
while ($row10 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res10)) {
    $adminid1 = $row10['adminid'];

    $elist = mysql_query("SELECT mail_address FROM ex_usrs WHERE id = '$adminid1'");
    $subject = "This is the subject";
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

    $message = '<h3>This is the message</h3>';

    ini_set(SMTP, "10.xxx.xxx.xx");
    ini_set(smtp_port, 25);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    ini_set("sendmail_from", "xx@xx.com");

    if (mysql_num_rows($elist) > 0) {
        while ($elist_result = mysql_fetch_array($elist)) {
            $headers = array('To' => $elist_result['mail_address']);
            mail($subject, $message, $headers);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error message is quite clear. `$headers` should not be an array.

Comment: This is happening because [`mail()`](http://php.net/mail) expects parameter 3 to be string, but and array is given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mixed up the parameters of the mail function ... your should be sending the following :

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

Note the `$to` field at the start. Change your while loop from

```
$headers = array('To' => $elist_result['mail_address']);
mail($subject, $message, $headers);
```

to

```
mail($elist_result['mail_address'],$subject, $message, $headers);
```

[The PHP documentation is very detailed](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Answer (score 1):

Option 3 has to be a string, but you gave an array:

```
$headers = array('To' => $elist_result['mail_address']);
mail($subject, $message, $headers);
```

Also Option 3 is the message.

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers ...
```

Have a look into the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

You're giving $headers as an array:

```
$headers = array('To' => $elist_result['mail_address']);
mail($subject, $message, $headers);
```

The correct syntax would be:

```
mail($elist_result['mail_address'], $subject, $message);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not me to make the -1.

But did you read the error? It explains your error. The correct usage of `mail` function can be found at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

According to php specification..first is to param.that you forgot

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```